# Symfony autoload skipping classes

Tags: php, symfony1, autoload

I have a symfony 1.4 project that has been is use for several years now. In the past few weeks the autoload has started skipping classes, arbitrarily as far as I can tell. This occurs in both plugins and files located in the lib/ directory.

If I rename the class the problem is solved. I've searched and there are no other classes of the same name in the entire project. There are also no errors in the classes. Many of these classes have not been edited in 2 years so literally nothing is changing in the classes.

When I clear the cache, some class is ignored on the next page load. classes in files in the same directory are picked up no problem.

Anyway, trying desperately to figure out what is going on. I can't find an error in symfony's error logs nor in apache or any other server log. But, I'm sure there is some logical reason why this is happening.

Also, just noticed, the autoload works on normal pages, it's only pages delivered over SSL that break.

Comment: Do you have any user cache like APC or memcached on your server?

Comment: Have APC but disabled it and cleared the cache just to be sure it wasn't the problem. I found that if I delete the file and then recreate it, it works, even if the name is identical. Is there some mechanism that could lock a file so that apache or the autoload  couldn't read it or something similar?

Comment: A problem of permissions, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late, but i had the same problem and i add to convert the end of line from unix to windows